# Time conversion so I can insert data in mysql

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Excuse my lack of knowledge playing with time in python3 but I am stuck for 30 minutes already in this problem so any help will be highly appreciated.

I have salesforce time coming in my script as `2016-11-15T23:49:48.000Z`. How can I convert it into mysql datetime format without storing it in a variable.

Desired output format: `2016-11-16 12:11:21.525885`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the time module's `strptime` referenced [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime).

I'm making some assumptions about the input data, but here's a format that will probably work:

```
import time
import datetime
def translate_timestamp(timestamp):
    t = time.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    s = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(t))
    return s.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

An example might be:

```
>>> translate_timestamp("2016-11-15T23:49:48.000Z")
'2016-11-15 23:49:48.000000'
```

Comment: So x needs to be replaced with timestamp.

Also I am seeing following error.
`TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'beatbox.xmltramp.Element'>`

FYI, I am using beatbox library to import data in python.

Comment: I resolved the issue but your answer helped. Thank you.